# Remove unwanted text from string

Tags: r, regex, rvest

I have a string "yada yada.useful text here. googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-447281037690072557-2'); });useful text here. yada yada". I want to remove the string "googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-447281037690072557-2'); });" but I can't.

I tried selecting the unwanted string using "^(google)*});", "^google*});" to no avail. Even "^google" or "^google*" does not do anything but "google" works fine. I used the gsub and str_remove functions but my selector doesnt work.

How do I remove the unwanted string? I searched the regex and adding ^ to a selector stops my code from working. What did I miss?

Comment: The `^` asserts the start of the string. You could use `\bgoogletag.*?}\);` but I think matching javascript code like this can be error prone. https://regex101.com/r/aFr13i/1

Comment: Also I used the regex "^google*});", for some reason the * doesnt appear even when I edit

Comment: That by itself is not a valid expression, but if you escape the parenthesis the pattern is `^google*}\);` where the `*` would repeat an `e` character 0 or more times matching for example `googl});`, `google});` and `googleeeeeee});` etc..

Comment: Yeah, forgot the "." before the "*". thanks. I need a new pair of glasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
library(stringr)

x <- "yada yada.useful text here. googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-447281037690072557-2'); });useful text here. yada yada"

x %>% str_remove("googletag.*\\}\\)")
```

**Explanation**

The regex looks for "googletag" (where your unwanted string starts)

.* means any number of characters

\\}\\) until we find })

the double backslashes are "R slang" other regex would mostly only use one backslash.

Comment: why does "googletag*" works and "google*" doesnt? I really have no idea.

Comment: Try `gsub("googletag.*\\}\\)\\W", "", x)`: this also removes the punctuation and the space at the end of the unwanted string. `\\W`(with capital W) matches anything that is **not* alphanumeric.

Comment: No, look more closely: it's `googletag.*`plus a little more, not `googletag*`--you are missing the `.`, which matches anything, whereas `*`is a **quantifying** expression to match zero or more times. So `.*` says "match anything any number of times".

Comment: Yeah, forgot the "." before the "*". Thanks a lot